# The forward slash is prefixed with a backward one in string laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to store a path in the database but the forward slash is prefixed with a backward one when I see it in mysql. How to fix this?

`["\/cars\/1_f202007c859996f7abc6c1af694b7fe5.jpg","\/cars\/1_755f1bda2c7a0c965b31786695059e8c.jpg"]`

This is the function:

```
foreach($images as $image){
     $image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $image);
     $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
     $unique_string = md5(microtime());
     $imageName = $user_id.'_'.$unique_string.'.'.'jpg';
     File::put(public_path('cars'). '/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));
     $array[] = '/cars/'.$imageName;
}
```

Comment: That's typical for a json string. It's escaping the slash.

Comment: *"How to fix this"* - You don't, it's not broken.

Comment: `json_decode` will give you the values as they are. Not sure what the issue is though.

Comment: use json_encode()